# Magento 2 Wishlist head title

Tags: xml, magento2

I'm Using Magento EE 2.2.2. I am trying to change the head title of wishlist "My Wish List" to "My Favourites". I am trying in XML `wishlist_index_index.xml` and added the below lines.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <head>
            <title>My Favourites</title>
        </head>
 </page>
```

But it is not working.

Comment: not working is not a helpful message. What's the output?

Comment: Hi phuclv,
It displayed the same title "My Wish List".

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Answer (score 1):

Two way to change Wish-list head title:

1. Override "Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist" and set title in "_prepareLayout" function.
2. Use csv or inline translation.

Comment: Thank you @Evince. It is working. The second option is better

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me.

Create di.xml file in your module app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Customer\Wishlist" />
</config>
```

Create Wishlist.php file  app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Block/Customer/Wishlist.php

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Moudle]\Block\Customer;

class Wishlist extends \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist
{
    
    /**
     * Preparing global layout
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Wish List'));
        
        return $this;
    }

}
```

After that run setup:di:compile command and cache flush command.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).